# Conversion og BMP instance to png

Tags: c#, php, bmp

I have function name uploadLayerIcons which is as follows:

```
    private void uploadLayerIcon(string LayerName)
    {
        Bitmap icon= new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\911\Prism\Prism_Resources\m.png");        

        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        icon.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        byte[] imageBytes = stream.ToArray();
        // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);

        HttpWebRequest m_ObjRequest; //Request which needed to be sent to server
        HttpWebResponse m_ObjResponse; // Response which is sent back from the server to the client

        StreamReader reader = null; // making a stream reader to read the web pageand initialize it to null


        string m_Url = "http://192.168.1.30/muneem/erp/uploadIcon.php" + "?bitmap=" + base64String + "&layerName=" + LayerName; // the url of that web page

        string m_Response = "";
        m_ObjRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m_Url); // creating the url and setting the values
        m_ObjRequest.Method = "GET";
        m_ObjRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        //m_ObjRequest.ContentLength = 500;
        m_ObjRequest.KeepAlive = false;

        m_ObjResponse = (HttpWebResponse)m_ObjRequest.GetResponse(); // getting response from the server
        using (reader = new StreamReader(m_ObjResponse.GetResponseStream())) // using stream reader to read the web page
        {
            m_Response = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close(); // Close the StreamReader
        }

        m_ObjResponse.Close();
        m_ObjRequest = null;
        m_ObjResponse = null;


    }
```

UploadIcon.php file is as follows:

```
<?php
 $bitmap=$_GET['bitmap'];
 $name=$_GET['layerName'];

$data = base64_decode($bitmap);

$filepath="app/uams/uploadedImages/".$name.".jpg";
 file_put_contents($filepath,$data);


?>
```

Its not converting correctly the same image which i have sent to server.

I have search on internet many thing but all in vain. I have also tried this thing

```
 Bitmap icon= new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\911\Prism\Prism_Resources\m.png");
 icon.save("Path of srrver")
```

But its not working.

Comment: You are converting png to bmp then transfering it and saving it directly to jpg?

Comment: yup but i am sending bmp string to server and saving bmp string to jpeg/png in server

Comment: Well no, you are saving bitmap data with .jpg extension. Changing the extension does not automagically conver the image to .jpg format. I suggest you send the png data to php, and then in php you do something like `$im = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($_GET['bitmap']));` and then `imagejpeg($im,$filepath)`. I will write this in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

So, you are doing it pretty much wrong. First of all, if you change the extension of the file to `.jpg` it does not automagically become `jpg` image.

So, what I suggest you to do is to send the raw `png` data instead of bitmap, and then using something like this in php:

```
<?
  $imagedata = $_POST["data"];
  $im = imagecreatefromstring($imagedata);
  $filepath="app/uams/uploadedImages/image.jpg";
  imagejpeg($im,$filepath);
?>
```

Also, as pointed out in previous answer by @DoXicK, do not send file by `GET` method, you should post it instead, and that is what this example is based on.

PHP's function `imagecreatefromstring` identifies the image type, and creates the gdlib object accordingly (but it does not work very well with bitmaps). That is why I suggested that you use raw `png` data instead of converting it to bitmap. Also, bitmap data is unneccesary large for transfer.

For `imagecreatefromstring` to work you need GD Library installed and enabled. To see if it is enabled create an empty file (named for example `info.php`) and inside it put only

```
<?
  phpinfo();
?>
```

If you see GD Support set to Enable on the page, when you open the file, you have gdlib enabled. If you do not see it, do the following:

On windows find `;extension=php_gd2.dll` in `php.ini` file of your php installation, and uncomment it (remove `;` from the beginning) so it now is `extension=php_gd2.dll` and then restart Apache.

On linux you need to do `sudo apt-get install php5-gd` and then restart Apache.

Comment: thanks for answer please tell me one thing more can u tell me how to send rawpng/ico data to server?

Comment: Well just dont read the file as bitmap, read the raw file data, and post it to the server.

Comment: What do you mean, like what?

Comment: System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));

Comment: Just make sure that you do base64_decode in php then, like `$imagedata = base64_decode($_POST['data']);`.

Comment: sir my client is saying he will give me bitmap instance and i have to make image and upload that instance to server. i have to work with bitmap

Comment: You can try this code with bitmap too, and let me know if it gives you some strange colors in the output jpeg, and we will seek to work it out. Test it first.

Comment: ok just clear me 1 thing i have to make raw data in desktop application form this code System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));?

Comment: I am not very good at C# but that seems about right. Can you test it and see? Isn't that easier?

Comment: imagecreatefromstring is giving error. I am getting 500 internal server error on this line

Comment: You need `gdlib` extension enabled. If on windows find `;extension=php_gd2.dll` in php.ini and remove the `;` at the begining and restart apache, if on linux do `sudo apt-get install php5-gd` and then restart apache.

Comment: sir i have sudo it but how to check in php.ini file for GD support? I am not getting anything when i search for GD or extension=?

Comment: sir i have checked i found gd.so file in usr/lib/php5/20090626. it means i have installed correctly, but still imagecreatefrom string is not running?

Comment: See if the extension is loaded by using the <? phpinfo(); ?> part that I added to my answer.

Comment: i cant see extension  in page(phpinfo()). isearched on internet and i found gd.so in usr/lib/php5/20090626

Comment: Well then maybe you need to comment it out in php.ini (remove `;` from the start of `; extension=gd.so`).

Answer (score 1):

1. you are loading a PNG to BMP file format
2. You are sending a file by GET
3. you are saving the BMP file as JPG te minute you receive the BMP

So:

1. Don't open as PNG as BMP. open a PNG as PNG as it is either smaller or the same size. There is no need for the BMP here...
2. POST it
3. Just because you call it a JPG, doesn't make it a JPG. It currently is a BMP, saved to a JPG.

IF it even saves a .jpg file, it is a .bmp file with the wrong extension.

Comment: sir whats the best way to upload an image to server?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/322464/Upload-a-file-using-Csharp-as-client-to-a-PHP-serv shows you how to easily do it :-) both the c# as the PHP side.

Comment: and is there any way to convert bitmap instance because my client is asking this he is saying he will give me bitmap instance in desktop application and i have to create png image from that instance to server

Comment: This is done a gazillion times and easily found on google. "PHP bmp to png" or "C# bmp to png". "C# upload file to php"